# Exact Search in Solr on a field

Tags: solr

I want to do exact match one of the fields(domain) in my collection.
Right now, if i search for "DIU" it brings me "DIU" & "DIU/DRRU", i only need "DIU".
When i search "DIU/DRRU" i need only "DIU/DRRU".
How i can achieve this ? i am using Solr 7.4

My schema settings are -

```
"name":"domain",
        "type":"text_general",
        "multiValued":false,
        "indexed":true,
        "stored":true},

{
        "name":"text_general",
        "class":"solr.TextField",
        "positionIncrementGap":"100",
        "multiValued":true,
        "indexAnalyzer":{
          "tokenizer":{
            "class":"solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"},
          "filters":[{
              "class":"solr.StopFilterFactory",
              "words":"stopwords.txt",
              "ignoreCase":"true"},
            {
              "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"}]},
        "queryAnalyzer":{
          "tokenizer":{
            "class":"solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"},
          "filters":[{
              "class":"solr.StopFilterFactory",
              "words":"stopwords.txt",
              "ignoreCase":"true"},
            {
              "class":"solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory",
              "expand":"true",
              "ignoreCase":"true",
              "synonyms":"synonyms.txt"},
            {
              "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"}]}},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a String field instead of a `text_general` based field - the `text_general` field (with the StandardTokenizer attached) will split on `/`. A `string` field will only give a match if the field matches exactly the same as the value stored.

Comment: You mean replace "name":"text_general", with string ??

Comment: yes, replace the fieldtype for the fields with String instead of test_general.

Comment: @user662285 Yup.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the field `domain` has `text_general` as the field type for your field.
Use `keywordTokenizer` for your field if you are looking for exact matches. As it does not create tokens of the text.

The `keywordTokenizer` is : `This tokenizer treats the entire text field as a single token.`

You can use the below field type for your field. The advantage would be it would help to search for words in all the case...UPPER and LOWER case both.

```
<fieldType name="lowercaseExactMatch" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```